# Using Python, how can I check if input is not the same as a defined character?

Tags: python

I was trying to do a car transmission type input validation, but why does it keep saying invalid input although I have entered the right input (M/A)?

```
print(">>> M - Manual\n>>> A - Auto")
transmission_type = input("Please select car transmission type (M/A): ")
while True:
     if transmission_type == '':
          transmission_type = input("Please select car transmission type (M/A): ")
     elif transmission_type != "M" or transmission_type != "A":
          print("Invalid input !")
          transmission_type = input("Please select car transmission type (M/A): ")
     else:
          print("Transmission type:",transmission_type)
          break
```

Comment: Your second condition always evaluates to `True`, did you mean `and` or alternatively `elif transmission_type not in ('M', 'A'):`

Comment: Also your first condition is redundant.

Comment: ok thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `and`, not `or`.

This will solve your problem and give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and`. This will give you the correct output.

In addition to that answer, I suggest using `in` to check if an input is possibly equal to multiple things.

```
print(">>> M - Manual\n>>> A - Auto")
transmission_type = input("Please select car transmission type (M/A): ")              
while True:
     if transmission_type == '':
          transmission_type = input("Please select car transmission type (M/A): ")
     elif transmission_type not in ('M', 'A'):
          print("Invalid input!")
          transmission_type = input("Please select car transmission type (M/A): ")
     else:
          print("Transmission type: ", transmission_type)
          break
```